# Keyboard event.charCode is always 0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, keyboard, addeventlistener

I'm trying to detect keyboard input and if the arrow keys are pressed, set the players next move to whatever was pressed. I'm listening for keyboard input using:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
```

This is the function that gets called:

```
public function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.charCode)
    {
        case 37:
            this.nextMove = "LEFT";
            break;
        case 38:
            this.nextMove = "UP";
            break;
        case 39:
            this.nextMove = "RIGHT";
            break;
        case 40:
            this.nextMove = "DOWN";
            break;
    }

    trace(event.charCode);
}
```

Thing is, `charCode` is always 0. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`keyCode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#keyCode) for what you're doing.